# editing a javascript file in a Tomcat web application

Tags: java, javascript, maven-2, tomcat6

I edited a .js file that is included by a .jsp file, but when i package and deploy the war the javascript behaviour does not change. I'm using maven as a package manager. I've ran mvn clean,compile, package and deployed the war to the webapps directory in the catalina_base, and also deleted the old web application folder.

Comment: What is your deployment structure? How are your files laid out?

Comment: You have no idea how many times this has bitten me as well. Matt and Anthony are right - clear your cache. Shortcut in most browsers is Ctrl+Shift+Del.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hum... Dumb question, but have you cleared your browser cache? 
If you did, try stopping the server and starting it again (with the war file in the deployment folder).
Also, take a look at [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) and [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) to learn about exploded contexts and application manager, so that you can achieve a faster development cycle.

Comment: haha, good answer! I did forget to clear the cache. Thanks to @matt b as well!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your web browser does not have the resource cached.

Of course, it's also possible that the change you made does not produce the behavior you desired. View the source (and headers) of the javascript file sent to your browser to verify if the changes are appearing.